# Angular 7 appilication cannot reach web API once published

Tags: angular, visual-studio, iis, .net-core

I have a Angular 7 Application with .Net core 2.1, once the application is publish it cannot reach the API, which means no calls can be made, but before i published the application everything worked fine.*( i use IIS 10 Express when published)*
What could be the problem and how can i fix this?

**Example of a call in my code that checks if the API is accessible:**

(this is the first call in my application)

```
let availabilityHTTPCall = this.http.get("/v1/CheckAvailability");
availabilityHTTPCall.subscribe(
  (result: boolean) => {
    this._webApiUnavalable = result;
    this.wizardOpen = true;
    console.log("HTTP Call returned data without error!", result);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("HTTP Call returned an error!", error);
    this._webApiUnavalable = false;
  },
  () => {
    console.log("HTTP Call complete!");
    this.PlacesOfService();
    this.LoadPhCodes();
  }
);
```

**What the API looks like in the controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("CheckAvailability")]
 public Boolean CheckAvailability()
 {
     return true;
 }
```

**I usually get one of the following errors**

"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost/"

"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

OR

"Http failure response for http://localhost/v1/CheckAvailability: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Because you're still targeting localhost?

Comment: From your Route attributute it looks like the valid url is http://localhost/CheckAvailability. Did you check your route if it includes 'v1'?

Comment: @PNDev....i did check it does contain v1 in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to you to change your API endpoint in ts file like:

in the head of file:

```
import {enviroment} from '../../../enviroment'; //<-- be sure to DONT import enviroment.prod


let availabilityHTTPCall = this.http.get(enviromen.API_URL + "/v1/CheckAvailability"); //< --HERE
availabilityHTTPCall.subscribe(
  (result: boolean) => {
    this._webApiUnavalable = result;
    this.wizardOpen = true;
    console.log("HTTP Call returned data without error!", result);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("HTTP Call returned an error!", error);
    this._webApiUnavalable = false;
  },
  () => {
    console.log("HTTP Call complete!");
    this.PlacesOfService();
    this.LoadPhCodes();
  }
);
```

then in your enviroment.ts file :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/',

};
```

and in your  enviroment.prod.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'https://YOUDOMAIN/api/',

};
```

so whe you build in the `PRODUCTION MODE (--prod)` it switch your `ENDPOINT` from `localhost:5000` to yours `DOMAIN URL`

Hope it helps you

(`localhost can't work for published app ..cause it will be the USER LOCALHOST and in that no WEBASERVER with any API is running`!!!

hope it helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

LocalHost is the standard host name given to the address of the local computer, and IP address of your localhost is 127.0.0.1.

From what I guess, your API is hosted on a server on your local machine. So when you are programming locally, angular can reach localhost because you are on the machine.

Your local API isn't published on the internet, thus it is only accessible locally. So when you publish your angular app, it cannot reach your API anymore.

What you have to do is to publish your API as well on a server being accessible accessible online, and change the reference accordingly.

Comment: I created the entire application in visual studio so when i publish the application its published together in one bundle the API and the Angular7 application.